# Somar valores de dentro de uma coluna com postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando somar os valores de dentro de uma coluna com postgres, a estrutura da tabela é a seguinte:

```
id    |nome_municipio    |valores
1     |Porto Alegre      |100.01;95.0;50.1
2     |Ivoti             |87.0;80.1;45.1
3     |Novo Hamburgo     |210.0;99.2;100.0
```

Gostaria que o resultado final fosse

```
id    |nome_municipio    |valores   
1     |Porto Alegre      |245.2
2     |Ivoti             |207.2
3     |Novo Hamburgo     |409.2
```

Isso é possível?

Postgres 9.1

Comment: Sim, com Stored Procedure. Diretamente no SQL não.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id , nome_municipio,  (SELECT SUM(s) FROM
UNNEST(CAST(regexp_split_to_array(valores, E';') as real[])) s)   from "tabela"
```

Comment: Eu estava fazendo uma resposta usando `regexp_split_to_table()`. Não seria mais fácil por permitir fazer o `select sum(s)` sem precisar da conversão?

Comment: Seria, mas o postgresql não permite sem fazer conversão explicita na parte do UNNEST :(